# how many full binary trees with 3 nodes

Tags: combinatorics

How many full binary trees can be created from n nodes?

I thought $2^{n-1}+1$ but it is wrong because it doesn't fit the case of $n=2$.

In particular the exercise wants the case $n=3$.

Comment: The $n=3$ case can be easily solved by hand. About the solution of the general problem, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: A full binary tree has an odd number of nodes: it is a simple induction since $1+(2a+1)+(2b+1)$ is odd. For example see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963312/prove-through-structural-induction-that-a-binary-tree-has-an-odd-number-of-nodes